# CentOS Group Permissions

Tags: centos, permissions, centos5, ftp, file-permissions

How do I give all users in the group `ftp-users` full read/write acces to `/var/www` recursively?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'adds /var/www to  ftp-users group

chgrp  -R ftp-users /var/www

'sets group read/write access

chmod  -R g+rw /var/www

Comment: I would have also added the command: find /var/www -type d -print | xargs chmod +s     so that new files created in the future would have the same group membership.  Mind you there is no inheritance in Linux for permissions after being initially set.